# what type of javascript datatype is this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

`console.log` writes this datatype -

```
<key1 : value1 , key2 : value2>
```

the syntax is not similar to neither object nor array. So what datatype is this?

here's how to reproduce.

install **bsv** library

```
const bsv = require("bsv");
console.log(bsv.PrivateKey.fromRandom())
```

from node terminal

```
> bsv = require("bsv");
> bsv.PrivateKey.fromRandom()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

What you're seeing is just an object, specifically a [`PrivateKey`](https://github.com/moneybutton/bsv/blob/eb9438489eda0a346731fb2afb5f28fcc66e012b/lib/privatekey.js) object from the [`bsv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bsv) library. The `bsv` library has a custom representation of the object when logged by `console.log` in outdated versions of Node.js.

### Details

I was finally able to replicate your output, getting this from an outdated copy of Node.js:

```
<PrivateKey: a909d298d55c8fa3afdb641eb46e90cebad4f2d3f5ee0d4149e3bac16f12ee5b, network: livenet>
```

As I said above, it's just a [`PrivateKey`](https://github.com/moneybutton/bsv/blob/eb9438489eda0a346731fb2afb5f28fcc66e012b/lib/privatekey.js) object from the `bsv` library. The reason you're seeing what you're seeing is that the `bsv` library uses a long-deprecated feature of Node.js: Node.js's `console.log` used to look for an `inspect` method and if it was present, would call that method to get a string representation of the object to log. `bsv` has an `inspect` method on `PrivateKey`, currently at [line 372](https://github.com/moneybutton/bsv/blob/eb9438489eda0a346731fb2afb5f28fcc66e012b/lib/privatekey.js#L372) (that line number will rot over time, of course).

You'll only see this in (slightly) outdated copies of Node.js. I stumbled across this solution because I tried it on CodeSandbox, which was using v10.20.1. This helpful message was just after the output in CodeSandbox:

> (node:887) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated

I've since replicated that locally by installing Node.js v10.20.1.

With an [up-to-date copy of Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) (v12.16.3 is the current LTS as I write this, v14.1.0 is the current version), Node.js doesn't look for or use an `inspect` method anymore, so you see Node.js's standard object output, along these lines:

```
PrivateKey {
  bn: BN {
    negative: 0,
    words: [
      66428877, 21624768,
      45502785, 19604474,
      35981886, 10091365,
      29744843, 24740201,
      15504496,  1628002,
             0
    ],
    length: 10,
    red: null
  },
  compressed: true,
  network: Network {
    name: 'livenet',
    alias: 'mainnet',
    pubkeyhash: 0,
    privatekey: 128,
    scripthash: 5,
    xpubkey: 76067358,
    xprivkey: 76066276,
    cashAddrPrefix: 'bitcoincash',
    cashAddrPrefixArray: [
      2,  9, 20, 3, 15,
      9, 14,  3, 1, 19,
      8
    ],
    networkMagic: <Buffer e3 e1 f3 e8>,
    port: 8333,
    dnsSeeds: [ 'seed.bitcoinsv.org', 'seed.bitcoinunlimited.info' ]
  },
  publicKey: [Getter]
}
```

So, again: It's just an object, shown in nonstandard format by the `bsv` library.